# Как вызвать exception'ы в математических функциях в C++?

Tags: c++, c, математика, обработка-ошибок, числа-с-плавающей-точкой

Мне нужно вызвать исключения во время работы программы в математических функциях, и отловить их.

Например, я вызывал ошибку деления на ноль

```
float division(int a,int b)
{
    if (b == 0)
    {
        throw "Деление на ноль!";
    }
    return a / b;
}

void runtime__error()
{
    try {
        float z = division(3,0);
        cout << z << endl;
    } catch (const char* msg) {
        cerr << msg << endl;
    }

}
```

Покажите пожалуйста примеры кода, вызывающие например overflow error в функции pow(). За любые другие примеры runtime ошибок из math.h буду благодарен

Comment: Эти математические функции перекочевали из Си. А в Си исключений нет. Эти функции могут возвращать какие-то спец. значение (`NaN` например) и/или устанавливать какое-то значение в `errno`. Так же можно использовать функции их [cfenv](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cfenv)

Comment: @EOF всё, тут я разобрался, а как тогда проверить, есть ли ошибка, когда я например вызываю acos(2), который возвращает nan? что нужно в условии писать?

Comment: Примерно так как [здесь](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/acos). А может проще проверять значение аргумента перед передачей в функцию.

Comment: @EOF нужна именно ошибка времени исполнения, то есть, надо во время работы вызвать ошибку и проверить

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну, примерно так можно (читайте [тут](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/math_errhandling) и [тут](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv/FE_exceptions)) -

```
void throw_fe()
{
    if (errno) throw runtime_error(strerror(errno));
    if(fetestexcept(FE_DIVBYZERO))     throw runtime_error("FE_DIVBYZERO");
    if(fetestexcept(FE_INEXACT))       throw runtime_error("FE_INEXACT");
    if(fetestexcept(FE_INVALID))       throw runtime_error("FE_INVALID");
    if(fetestexcept(FE_OVERFLOW))      throw runtime_error("FE_OVERFLOW");
    if(fetestexcept(FE_UNDERFLOW))     throw runtime_error("FE_UNDERFLOW");
}

double Pow(double x, double y)
{
    errno = 0;
    feclearexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT);
    double z = pow(x,y);
    throw_fe();
    return z;
}

double Sqrt(double x)
{
    errno = 0;
    feclearexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT);
    double z = sqrt(x);
    throw_fe();
    return z;
}

double Log(double x)
{
    errno = 0;
    feclearexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT);
    double z = log(x);
    throw_fe();
    return z;
}

int main()
{
    try {
        double q = Sqrt(-2) + Pow(1e20,1e20);
        printf("log(0) = %lf, Q = %lf\n", Log(0), q);
    } catch(exception&e)
    {
        cout << "Catch: " << e.what()  << endl;
    }
}
```

Только вот, увы, не гарантирую, что это верное, переносимое, везде работающее решение... Но на VC++ и [GCC](https://ideone.com/6xATJw) вроде как отрабатывает.

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*

Comment: спасибо большое!)) А не подскажете, как можно в сишном варианте проверять ошибки? Вот например, pow(5,1000000000) вызываю, оно мне возвращает inf, как проверить, и сказать, что произошло переполнение?

Comment: Точно так же - просто без генерации исключения :) Например,, в случае ошибки эта `throw_fe();` не генерирует исключение, а возвращает `true`, а без ошибки - `false`. Посмотрите, кстати, примеры по ссылкам из ответа.

Comment: спасибо большое! :D